# Can we have 2 different type of custom views in single ListActivity

Tags: android

I try to mimic

[image]

By writing my own custom view (to display individual stock information) for ArrayAdapter.

[custom_row_view.xml](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock-android/blob/c89aede414fd73e45475cf5b0abd1d5cc1164150/res/layout/custom_row_view.xml)

```
// OrderAdapter is derived from ArrayAdapter.
OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, 
    R.layout.custom_row_view, new ArrayList<Object>());
```

The code for `OrderAdapter` is as follow.

```
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TransactionSummary> {

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<TransactionSummary> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, parent, false);
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

But in the constructor of ArrayAdapter, it only accept 1 type custom view. Hence, I have no idea how I can fit in another type of custom view (to display total of ALL stocks summary) at the end of this list.

May I know how I can have 2 different custom views for a single ListActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a view ID of 0 to ArrayAdapter's constructor.  You will then need to override a few methods:

- getViewTypeCount() to return the number of types of views that you have (2, in your case)
- getItemViewType() to return the view type of a given item.  Note, here, that this can be confusing: you do NOT return the layout ID here, but a number between 0 and getViewTypeCount().
- getView() to create and return the view

Read the help on BaseAdapter at http://http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html for good information.  Respond back if you need additional help.

--randy

Comment: May I know what is the meaning of having view ID 0 to ArrayAdapter? I do not see 0 case being mentioned in the documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, java.util.List<T>)

Comment: It's really just any invalid resource id.  If you have an invalid layout id and don't override getView(), you'll get a NullReferenceException (lovely, huh?), so having an invalid ID here does two things for you, really:  #1, the code doesn't look confusing, referencing a valid layout id that is in fact not used, and #2, forcing you to make sure you override the proper method because you'll crash otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.second_custom_row_view, new ArrayList<Object>());` then probably you'll be able to have another custom row view. But if you mean to have both of them at the same time. Maybe you should do the above one-after-another, subsequently, if that is possible not just theoretically.

Answer (score -2):

In the getView() method of your custom adapter you can inflate a diffrent layout for a particular object from your list.

You will most likely do this in the following way:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView==null){
             if(myObjects.get(position).isCustom()
                 convertView=inflate(R.layout.custom);
             else
                 convertView=inflate(R.layout.regular);
        }
        //update views...
    }
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: If he uses inflating, he should pass to the adapter `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` so he have child view where inflate either regular or custom